# ARM Template unable to set $connections

Tags: validation, connection, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I have created an ARM template in Visual Studio project with connection to slack. When I connect to slack in Azure portal - everything is fine. My slack API connection is authorized and works. My problem is with deployment and setting `$connections`.

Here is my template

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    <template-params>
  },
  "variables": {
    "slack": "[concat(parameters('appPrefix'), '-slack-', parameters('environment'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "name": "[variables('slack')]",
      "properties": {
        "api": {
          "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', resourceGroup().location, '/managedApis/slack')]"
        },
        "displayName": "Slack",
        "parameterValues": {}
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[parameters('logicAppName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
      "location": "[parameters('logicAppLocation')]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "LogicApp"
      },
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "properties": {
        "definition": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
          "actions": {
            "Collecting_went_wrong": {
              "inputs": {
                "host": {
                  "connection": {
                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['slack']['connectionId']"
                  }
                },
                "method": "post",
                "path": "/chat.postMessage",
                "queries": {
                  "channel": "<channel>",
                  "text": "<message>",
                  "username": "<user>"
                }
              },
              "runAfter": {},
              "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
          },
          "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
              "type": "object",
              "defaultValue": {
              }
            }
          },
          "triggers": {
           <trigger>
          }
        },
        "parameters": {
          "$connections": {
            "value": {
              "slack": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', variables('slack'))]",
                "connectionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', variables('slack'))]",
                "connectionName": "slack"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', variables('slack'))]"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

The 'fun' part is validation of template during the deployment:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 17:08:51 - Resource Microsoft.Logic/workflows 'reporting-reminder-logic-app-dev' 
failed with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": "ConnectionsParameterInvalid",
    "message": "The provided API connection parameter 'slack' is missing the required property 'id'."
  }
}'
```

I'm really confused here.

What I tried to deploy it as `connection` and added `$connection` parameter definition as well, deployment went through. Nevertheless, when I changed `connection` to `$connections` in template parameters, Azure portal throw at me the same validation error.

Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue was about different ID in resources -> Microsoft/Web.connections -> properties -> id and slack -> connection. Once this connection ids were the same, the validation passed.

So it's only confusing validation message.